# Why Remmina RDP doesn't work and Windows Remote Desktop Client Does?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I usually connect to several different remote desktops using a VPN and Remmina (to many different OS, including win10), but for some reason, there is a specific Win 10 machine that Remmina does not work. I know the issue is not with the VPN, because I can ping the server and connect to some apps being served only on its local network. The most weird thing, is that if I boot a windows 10 VM and connect via Windows Remote Desktop Client, it connects perfectly (VPN connected on host machine). How can I debug this? The message displayed is simply "Cannot connect to the RDP Server".

Remmina message:

```
[09:42:10:348] [16164:17224] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 131
[09:42:10:348] [16164:17224] [ERROR][com.freerdp.common.settings] - [freerdp_settings_get_bool] Invalid key index 0
[09:42:10:523] [16164:17224] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - Certificate verification failure 'self-signed certificate (18)' at stack position 0
[09:42:10:523] [16164:17224] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - CN = {IP}
[09:42:19:536] [16164:17224] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Timeout waiting for activation
libfreerdp returned code is 00000000
```

But the first 2 errors and 2 warns show on successfulconnections too.

When using xfreerdp I get this message:

```
[09:19:11:173] [14593:14594] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - Certificate verification failure 'self-signed certificate (18)' at stack position 0
[09:19:11:173] [14593:14594] [WARN][com.freerdp.crypto] - CN = {IP}
[09:28:28:031] [17164:17165] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.connection] - Timeout waiting for activation
[09:28:28:032] [17164:17164] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_abort_connect:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_CANCELLED [0x0002000B]
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it by increasing this parameter `/timeout:60000`
[On Remmina](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4pN0.png)
I guess it's just that Windows RDP is more tolerant by default.